# How to Display BusyIndicator while UserControl loads

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have an app with a menu.  When Item 1 is Selected, UserControl1 is displayed.

The issue is that UserControl1 is full of 3rd party components and takes about 4 seconds to load.  I would like to display a BusyIndicator so the user doesn't think that nothing is happening.

The issue is that even though I have a toolkit: BusyIndicator and set it to busy, it doesn't show until after UserControl1 loads.  This of course defeats the purpose of the BusyIndicator.

Since the load of the control is on the UI thread, the BusyIndicator never has a chance to fire up until it is too late.

I need to somehow fire off the BusyIndicator, let the UI update, then fire off the load of the Control.  Then turn off the BI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by the use of a timer.